# Exchange on-premise create mailbox or login using access token bearer

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, exchange-server, exchange-server-2019

We have an external oauth2 server for SSO.

Now we must use that server to authenticate our users.

We are not allowed to create users, we just have to authenticate the users via SSO and get the information via Access Token, and based on that token we have to either create a mailbox for new users or login to the mailbox if the user already has a mailbox created.
the SSO server guys provide us with the ClientID, ClientSecret, RedirectURI, etc...
In addition to the below URL:

https://< SSO-Server>/oauth2/authorize/?client_id=< ClientID>&response_type=token&redirect_uri=https://< Exchange-Server>/owa/&scope=profile

We are using Exchange Server 2019 CU 13 on-premise, I don't know what to do!
I'm not sure how to config the server.
I'd appreciate any help.

I tried to redirect the owa to the above link using
"Set-OrganizationConfig -AdfsIssuer"
It will redirect to the SSO and then SSO will authenticate the user and redirect the user to the specific link I provide + an Access Token
But how can I use that access token to create a new mailbox user?